# Pluribus games data

Tags: hand-history

Do you know if there is a way to retrieve data from the 10 000 hands played by Pluribus.
Pluribus is an IA which dominated in 6-player table against very strong human players.

The developers said that they won't reveal the code but I was wondering if it is possible to find the data frop the game played.
So at least we can try to understand how this IA played.

Comment: Finally I found some information here: https://www.reddit.com/r/poker/comments/cdhasb/download_all_10000_hands_that_pluribus_poker_ai/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reddit is  great work from kevinwangg treated hands for pt4. Well pokerstars format. Original hands are https://science.sciencemag.org/content/early/2019/07/10/science.aay2400 in the annex as published by CMU